# Clicking links: cannot open exit

Tags: firefox, default-programs, html

Sometimes, when I click on links it ends up opening Kate with an error message saying that the contents are too long, instead of opening Firefox as expected. This might have been because I set the default app to open .html files to be Kate, because I do occasionally do web dev, editing .html, .css, and .js files as text, instead of opening the browser, and I'd like to keep that behavior - .html files should open as text, and if I want to actually render it I'd open a browser first.

Somehow, links end up trying to open with a program named `exit`. Worse, sometimes it opens `exit`, other times it opens Firefox as expected. Regardless, any ideas how I can achieve the result I want (links always open in Firefox, but .html files should open with Kate or whatever editor I choose) ?

I am using Kubuntu 20.10, if it matters.

Thank you for your time

Comment: What makes you think links *are* opening with a program named `exit`?  What are you seeing?

Comment: @MartinThornton I remember I redirected _something_ to `exit`... I'm just not sure what and I can't find the setting again. When the links open in Kate, it first shows a message saying `Cannot open with exit` or something similar.